# CoreBluetooth - get BLE Genertic Attribute Profile raw bytes

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have a view controller that scans for BLE beacons that are advertising **only** and do now allow incoming connections. I can see the bytes that I want by inspecting the service data section (`CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey`) of the advertisement, but I can't actually access the raw bytes of the data as variable.

Here is the CM callback:

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    var advBytes: String!
    
    if let dictionary = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] as? [String: Any] {
        if let gatt = dictionary["Generic Attribute Profile"] as? [String: String] {
            advBytes = gatt["bytes"]?[2...]
        } else {
            print("Can't convert byte array to string")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Couldn't decode advertisement \(advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey])")
    }
```

When the code is run, the console outputs:

```
Couldn't decode advertisement Optional({
    "Generic Attribute Profile" = {length = 7, bytes = 0x6413000a000000};
})
```

How can I access this `bytes` part of the GATT as a variable?

Comment: Because it's not a `[String: String]`, it's a `[CBUUID: Data]`, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey

Comment: @Larme As the output of running the code is from the **first** else clause, it leads me to believe that actually it's the first if that's failing (`as? [String: Any]`), not the second (`as? [String: String]`)

Comment: `advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey]` is a `[CBUUID: Data]`, sorry, I mistype.

Comment: Thank you @Larme that works! If you provide your response as a full answer I will mark as correct.
As a second question, do you know how I now can extract from this Data variable, which contains `0x6413000a000000`? For example, I need to separate it into certain bytes, like `64`, `13`, `00`, `0a` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the doc of [`CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataservicedatakey), the value is `[CBUUID: Data]`.

So it should be:

```
if let dictionary = advertisementData[CBAdvertisementDataServiceDataKey] as? [CBUUID: Data] {

}
```

Now, if I remember correctly, the Service ID you are looking for GATT, is `1801`. It's just that Apple translate it automatically into a human readable "Generic Attribute Profile". You can test it with this:

```
let service = CBUUID(string: "1801")
print("Service UUID: \(service.uuidString) - \(service)")
```

They must have override description of `CBUUID` to print "words" when it's a known UUID.

Now, you could do this:

```
let genericAttributeProfileData = dictionary[CBUUID(string: "1801")]
let subData = genericAttributeProfileData[0...0]
// etc.
```